# Filter Duplicate elements from a [[String]] Haskell

Tags: haskell, duplicates

I have a list in the form `[["A1","A1","A1"] .. ["G3","G3","G3"]]` which contains many duplicate elements like `["A1","A2","A3"]` and `["A3","A2","A1"]`.

How do I filter out such duplicate elements?

if check the above two elements for equality, it shows false

```
*Main> ["A1","A2","A3"] == ["A3","A2","A1"]
False
```

Comment: What's your definition of duplicate? Same elements in a different order? Sounds like you should be using a [multiset](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-0.3.3/docs/Data-MultiSet.html) rather than a list for `["A1", "A2", "A3"]`.

Answer (score 4):

[`nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=nubBy) is a relevant function that removes duplicates from a list via an arbitrary equality test.

A version of the function you're looking for is:

```
import Data.List (sort, nubBy)

removeDuplicates' :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeDuplicates' = nubBy (\l1 l2 = sort l1 == sort l2)
```

Of course, this does require that `a` is an `Ord`, not just an `Eq`, as well as using `sort`, which is (as stated below) an expensive function. So it is certainly not ideal. However, I don't know specifically how you want to do the equality tests on those lists, so I'll leave the details to you.

Answer (score 1):

[@AJFarmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035734/67579) solves the issue. But it can be done a bit more efficient: since `sort` is an expensive function. We want to save on such function calls.

We can use:

```
import Data.List(nubBy, sort)
import Data.Function(on)

removeDuplicates' :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeDuplicates' = map snd . nubBy ((==) `on` fst) . map ((,) =<< sort)
```

what we here do is first construct a `map ((,) =<< sort)`. This means that for every element `x` in the original list, we construct a tuple `(sort x,x)`. Now we will perform a `nubBy` on the first elements of the two tuples we want to sort. After we have sorted, we will perform a `map snd` where we - for every tuple `(sort x,x)` return the second item.

We can generalize this by constructing a `nubOn` function:

```
import Data.List(nubBy)
import Data.Function(on)

nubOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
nubOn f = map snd . nubBy ((==) `on` fst) . map ((,) =<< f)
```

In that case `removeDuplicates'` is `nubOn sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You may not even need to sort. You just need to see if all items are the same like;

```
\xs ys -> length xs == (length . filter (== True) $ (==) <$> xs <*> ys)
```

you just need to know that `(==) <$> ["A1","A2","A3"] <*> ["A3","A2","A1"]` would in fact return `[False,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,False]`

As per @rampion 's rightful comment let's take it further and import `Data.Set` then it gets pretty dandy.

```
import Data.Set as S

equity :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
equity = (. S.fromList) . (==) . S.fromList

*Main> equity ["A1","A2","A3"] ["A3","A2","A1"]
True
```

Comment: If both lists are of length `n`, sorting then comparing is `O(n log n)`, but this check is `O(n ^ 2)`, strictly more expensive.